# Access violation freeing library that returns a interface for a class within the dll

Tags: delphi, dll, interface, loadlibrary

I have a dll that contains a class that implements a interface. The dll has an exported method that returns the interface.

I can explicit load the dll succefully, but when I try to use Free Library I get Access Violation. I did not tried use implicit link, because I need use the explicit mode.

If I just load the library and free right after, without geting the interface, everything works fine.

**Dll**

```
library Tef;

uses
  uTTefFacade;

{$R *.res}

exports
  CreateTef;

begin
end.
```

*Interface in dll:*

```
type
  ITefFacade = interface
  ['{77691DD1-C6E9-4F75-951F-BFA1468DC36C}']
    function IniciarTransacao(AParam: TTefIniciarTransacaoParamDTO): TTefIniciarTransacaoResultDTO;
  end;
```

*Class in dll:*

```
 type
      TTefFacade = class (TInterfacedObject, ITefFacade)
      private    
        function IniciarTransacao(AParam: TTefIniciarTransacaoParamDTO): TTefIniciarTransacaoResultDTO;
      public
        constructor Create;
        destructor Free;
      end;

function CreateTef: ITefFacade; export; stdcall;

function CreateTef: ITefFacade;
begin
  Result := ITefFacade(TTefFacade.Create);
end;
```

**Exe:**

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  CreateTef: function: ITefFacade; stdcall;
begin
  try
    FTef := nil;

    FHTef := LoadLibrary('Tef.dll');
    if (FHTef > 0) then
    begin
      @CreateTef := GetProcAddress(FHTef, 'CreateTef');
      if (@CreateTef <> nil) then
        FTef := CreateTef;
    end;

    if (FTef = nil) then
      ShowMessage('Error.');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Erro: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

*And here in the calling Free Library, access violation occurs.*

```
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeLibrary(FHTef);
end;
```

Comment: Do you set your reference of the FTef anywhere to nil before unload?
If not that could be  the reason.

Comment: It worked, thank you! I tried FreeAndNil before and it did not worked, I did not thought in just assign nil.

Comment: I think it is time to learn more about the differences between classes and interfaces, FreeAndNil on  a Interface is a nogo

Comment: Also, in `TTefFacade`, if you intent to implement a proper destructor then you need to change `destructor Free;` to ``destructor Destroy; override;`

Answer (score 4):

You have to `nil` the `FTef` reference before releasing the DLL.

The object behind the interface lives in the DLL, you should respect this. If you try to unload the DLL without releasing the interface first, there will be problems when the object is accessed after the unload (such as when Delphi auto-nils the reference when it goes out of scope).